# Can't get XMLHttpRequest response with async:true

Tags: javascript, ajax, django, python-3.x

In Rich Text Editor I want to upload local images into server media folder. For this, I made a XMLHttpRequest. The request with a downloadable file is sent to the server, then a function on the server saves the file and returns its url. The returned url should be displayed on the Text Editor dialog box. At first I tried this code and everything worked fine with **async:false** parameter. In the dialog box appeared relative url of file and I could load it on the view page. The picture below shows successful image upload.

```
file_picker_callback: function(cb, value, meta) {
        if (meta.filetype == 'file') {
            var input = document.createElement('input');
            input.setAttribute('type', 'file');
            input.setAttribute('accept', 'MIME_type');

            input.onchange = function () {
                var file = this.files[0];
                var reader = new FileReader();

                // FormData
                var fd = new FormData();
                var files = file;
                fd.append("file",files);
                var location = "";

                // AJAX
                jQuery.ajax({
                    url: "/fileupload/file/",
                    type: "POST",
                    data: fd,
                    dataType: 'json',
                    contentType: false,
                    processData: false,
                    async: false,
                    success: function(response){
                       location = response.fileurl;
                    }
                });

                reader.onload = function(){
                //call the callback and populate the Title field with the file name
                   cb(location, { download : files.name });
                };
                reader.readAsDataURL(files);
            };
            input.click();
        }
    },
```

[image: Editor Dialog box]

But then, in the console I get "Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects" message. 
Then i changed **async:true** and code stopped working. The file is still uploaded to the server but the url is not displayed in the dialog box. I think the FileReader does not get the server response in time. How can I make FileReader wait for the end of the XMLHttpRequest? Below is my handler on Python:

```
@require_POST
@csrf_exempt
def file_upload(request):
    data = UploadFile.objects.create(file=request.FILES['file'], related_post_id=1,)
    return JsonResponse({'fileurl': data.file.url})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just move the code that reads the file inside the AJAX call `success` function. Something like this:

```
jQuery.ajax({
    url: "/fileupload/file/",
    type: "POST",
    data: fd,
    dataType: 'json',
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    success: function(response){
        var location = response.fileurl;
        reader.onload = function(){
            //call the callback and populate the Title field with the file name
            cb(location, { download : files.name });
        };
        reader.readAsDataURL(files);
    }
});
```